# Repeating Decimals

Tags: problem-solving

I'm just wondering how do we simplify repeating decimals into a fraction in general?

Like, for example,

$$0.5656\dots$$

$$0.12424\dots$$

$$4.23777\dots$$

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a formula existing that I can use?  Everytime when I go to math competition I'm stuck with problems like this

Answer (score 11):

I’ll illustrate the technique with $1.23456456456\dots$; you should be able to generalize it pretty easily.

Let $x=1.23456456456\dots$. Then $10^3x=1234.56456456\dots$, so

$$\begin{align*}
999x&=1234.564\,564\,564\dots-1.234\,564\,564\dots\\
&=1233.330\,000\,000\dots\\
&=1233.33\,.
\end{align*}$$

Multiply by $10^2$ to get rid of the decimals: $99900x=123333$. Now just solve for $x$.

At the first step I simply shifted the decimal point by the length of the repeating block. That ensured that the subtraction would leave me with a terminating decimal.

Comment: I normally demonstrate this technique by subtracting 100x from 10000x instead.  Functionally they're equivalent; but making the decimal part go away completely in a single step seems to result in more people getting the concept immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295195/h0w-t0-prove-that-periodic-decimal-numbers-are-rational-a-1-a-kb-1b-2-b-l/295304#295304). That link should answer your question.

Here, I'll just give you an example, if you want the step-by-step instruction, you can look at the link above.

$\begin{align}4.12222... &= 4.1 + 0.0222...\\
& = 4.1 + \frac{0.2222...}{10} \\
& = \frac{41}{10} + \frac{\frac{2}{9}}{10} \\
& = \frac{41}{10} + \frac{2}{90}\\
&= \frac{371}{90} \end{align}$

Answer (score 3):

Others already indicated how to show it, but here's the result.
$$0.a_1a_2\dots a_n a_1 a_2 \dots = \frac{a_1a_2\dots a_n}{\underbrace{999\cdots9}_{n \text{ nines}}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

There is a method for this, for example, let's take $4.23777\ldots$. The decimal not repeating part is $4.23$ and the repeating part is $0.00777\ldots$. The idea is to seperate the repeating decimal part and then cancel it. Write $x=4.23777\ldots$ and do the following
$$x=4.23777\ldots$$
$$100x=423.777\ldots$$
$$1000x=4237.77\ldots$$
$$1000x-100x=4237.77\ldots-423.777\ldots=(4237-423)+(0.777\ldots-0.777\ldots)=3814$$
$$900x=3814$$
$$x=\frac{3814}{900}=\frac{1907}{450}$$
Therefore $4.23777\ldots=\frac{1907}{450}$.

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your number have a form
$$
N = I_1I_2\ldots I_n.D_1D_2\ldots D_m \left(P_1 P_2 \ldots P_k\right)
$$
where $I_1I_2\ldots I_n$ is an integer part, $D_1D_2\ldots D_m$ is non repeating part of the decimal, and $P_1P_2\ldots P_k$ is repeating part of the decimal. So, it's most general form of such number. For example
$$
N = 455.01102(979665) = 455.01102\ 979665\ 979665\ 979665 \ldots
$$
so
$$
I_1 = 4;\quad I_2 = 5; \quad I_3 = 5 \\
D_1 = 0; \quad D_2 = 1; \quad D_3 = 1; \quad D_4 = 0; \quad D_5 = 2 \\
P_1 = 9; \quad P_2 = 7;\quad P_3 = 9; \quad P_4 = 6; \quad P_5 = 6; \quad P_6 = 5
$$
Then, you can rewrite is as
$$
N = I_1I_2\ldots I_n.D_1D_2\ldots D_m + 0.\underbrace{000\ldots 0}_{\text{$m$ times}}\left(P_1 P_2 \ldots P_k\right) = \\
= I_1I_2\ldots I_n.D_1D_2\ldots D_m + 10^{-m} \times 0.\left(P_1 P_2 \ldots P_k\right)
$$
So, you really have to consider $P = 0.\left(P_1 P_2 \ldots P_k\right)$ part only.

As it was suggested, multiply the whole thing to $10^k$ and subtract initial number, so
$$
10^kP-P = \underbrace{999\ldots 9}_{\text{$k$ times}}P = P_1P_2 \ldots P_k.(P_1P_2\ldots P_k)-0.(P_1P_2\ldots P_k) = P_1P_2\ldots P_k$$
so you can find now
$$
P = \frac {P_1P_2\ldots P_k}{\underbrace{999\ldots 9}_{\text{$k$ times}}}
$$
and finally
$$
N = I_1I_2\ldots I_n + \frac {D_1D_2\ldots D_m}{10^m} + \frac {P_1P_2\ldots P_k}{10^m\underbrace{999\ldots 9}_{\text{$k$ times}}}
$$

Comment: I think it's $10^{-m-1}$, not $m-1$

Comment: @DonLarynx nice catch.

Comment: Consider $\frac{1}{7} = 0.(142857)$. Then $P = 0.(142857)$. Then, since $k = 6$, $10^kP - P = 9999999(0.142857) =$ $$142857.(142857) - 0.(142857) = 142857 \neq 1428569.857$$ Something is wrong with the answer.

Comment: @DonLarynx you have one too many `9' in your factor.

Comment: then I just get $999999P$ which is still not equivalent to $142857$

Comment: @DonLarynx it is though.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Look at the decimals of $x$ and $100x$, where $x=0.5656...$, for example, to get an idea of a general procedure. Obviously what you are looking for is an expression in fractions for $x$.