# Express 2.909090909... as a Rational Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Put in the form $p/q$ with no common factors. My initial thought was to try to sum up the $.9090$ by noting $90/10^2$ repeats. However, I can't see what good that ultimately would do in finding the answer.

Comment: Hint: 90/99 = 0.90909...

Comment: $100x-x=290-2$.

Comment: A general method for solving problems like this is found in the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/295195/139123

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$2.90909090... = 2+9\sum_{k=0}^\infty 10^{-(2k+1)} = 2+\frac{9}{10} \frac{1}{1-10^{-2}} = 2+\frac{90}{99}=\frac{32}{11}$$

Comment: The numerator and denominator are both divisible by $9$, so they can be reduced.

Comment: True, i'll edit my answer thanks

Comment: That's good. In all fairness, though, $\frac{288}{99}$ is still a correct answer unless the problem says "a rational number _in lowest terms_."

Comment: It does say that, just differently.

Answer (score 2):

$x=2.90909090...$ so $100x=290.90909...$, so $99x=288$.  Hence $x=288/99$

Answer (score 2):

This is a neat trick that can also be used to show $0.99999... = 1$. Set $$x = 2.909090.... \quad \mbox{so that} \quad 100x = 290.909090...$$ Therefore,
$$
99x = 100x - x = 290.909090... - 2.909090... = 288,
$$
so $2.909090... = x = 288/99$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2.909090\ldots$ and compute $99x = 100x-x$. This should be an integer (the fractional part is the same after multiplying by $100$, so $x$ is $\frac{\text{something}}{99}$.

Answer (score 1):

All repeating decimals with a zero in the one's place may be easily expressed as a fraction by putting the repeating sequence as the numerator, and a sequence of 9's in the denominator as long as the repeating sequence.

Thus, $0.90909090... = \frac{90}{99}$

So, we could quickly say that:
$2.9090... = 2 + \frac{90}{99} = \frac{198}{99} + \frac{90}{99} = \frac{288}{99}$

Comment: I always do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 2.9090909\ldots.$
Then add $10x$ and $x$ as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rcr}
10x & = & 29.090909\ldots   \\
+\  x &   & +\ 2.909090\ldots \\ \hline
11x & = & 31.999999\ldots
\end{array}$$

Therefore $11x = 32,$
since $0.999999\ldots = 1$ (exactly, not merely an approximation).
Solve for $x$.

---

The answer above exploits the known fact that $\frac1{11} = 0.09090909\ldots.$
For a more general problem you can always get an answer by multiplying
by $10^n - 1$ where $n$ is the number of repeating digits.
In this case you would multiply by $99$, which happens to be $9\cdot11$,
and you end up solving an equation like the one above except that
both sides have been multiplied  by $9$.